# Pointwise (in time) convergence in $H^{-1}$ implies pointwise weak convergence in $L^q$, why?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $u_n \to u$ in $C^0([0,T];H^{-1}(\Omega))$ and suppose $\lVert u_n \rVert_{L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty(\Omega))} \leq C$ for all $n$.

It follows that for almost all $t$, $u_n(t)$ is bounded in $L^\infty(\Omega)$, so we can extract a weak-* convergent subsequence and after a bit of work we can show that
$$\text{for almost all $t$} \qquad u_n(t) \rightharpoonup u(t) \text{ in $L^q(\Omega)$}$$
for all $q < \infty$.

I want to show that this weak convergence holds for **all** $t$.

From personal correspondence, I have been told that

> The key point is that one already has convergence in the larger space. So one already knows that pointwise, i.e. for **all** $t$, $u(t)$ converges in this larger space. But 
>   since it is also bounded in $L^\infty$, $u(t)$ **[for almost all $t$ -- riem's note]** will also converge weak-* up to a subsequence, and the limit is the same are identified as 
>   distributions. The same is true for any $L^q$, $q<\infty$.

Simply put, I don't get why it must hold for all $t$.